# How to return a value from within closure to external scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I came across the need to return a value from one function to another and for a while scratched my head in confusion when this simple task didn't work. I then realised I was operating within a closure function (or anonymous function?) and can't find documentation on how to release a variable out of such a function's scope.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
function aFunc()
{
   var result;
   object.event = function(){
      result = true;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Nor does returning from inside the closure. Do I need to do both? I tried using a global variable within the largest scope possible (outside of all functions) and this didn't work either. What am I missing?

I'm not sure whether I'm using the term closure correctly, I'm referring to the anonymous function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the closure:

```
function aFunc() {
   var result;
   object.event = function() {
      result = true;
   };
   object.event();
   return result;
}
```

Or, if it runs elsewhere, this is a timing issue. You can have something like a *promise*:

```
function aFunc() {
   var promise = { hasRun: false, result: null };
   object.event = function() {
      result.hasRun = true;
      result.result = true; // or something else...
   };
   return promise;
}

// check if it has run and get the result:

if (promise.hasRun) {
  // access promise.result
}
```

But, a simple callback should suffice. Since you mentioned the `XMLHttpRequest` object, you should be able to attach a callback to its `onreadystatechange` event, or pass a callback to `aFunc`:

```
function aFunc(callback) {
   object.event = function() {
      var result = true;
      callback(result);
   };
}
```

Then your callback gets called with the result at the time it is available.

Comment: The closure does run, the object and event in question is an xmlhttp ready state, maybe my example has confused things.

Comment: Then it's a timing issue, it definitely doesn't run before you return its result. What you need then, is to return a _promise_, something you can check later; or simply use a callback.

Comment: Ah I see. What would a promise look like?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using my own call back, which works a treat :)

Answer (score 3):

You could pass an object to the closure, whose attribute 'result' it would set when the function is called.

```
function aFunc (foo) {
    object.event = function() {
        foo.result = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the value of `result` is returned by `aFunc`, rather than a reference to it, which means that any subsequent change of `result` that happens inside the closure would not affect the `result` that was returned earlier.

Comment: The example above is a simplification of the function I'm having trouble with. Result is determined within the closure(?) and depending on several conditions may or may not be true. So I couldn't pass a predetermined value for result into it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The point is that you assign to an attribute of a known object and will have access to the result.

Comment: If you assign to a local variable result within the function aFunc *after* aFunc has finished executing, you have little chance of retrieving the value

Comment: Passing an object seems like the simplest idea, but would this work given the timing issue?

Comment: Well, it will assign the necessary value to the field 'result' of 'foo' when the closure is executed. You have to store the object till then.

Comment: @Lee by the way, the thing Jordão calls a "promise" is exactly the same as the foo object in the example above. Whether the object is created inside the function that assignes the closure or provided by the caller is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved the problem passing value to a callback.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible; the code

```
object.event = function(){
    result = true;
}
```

doesn't actually execute `result = true;`, it just defines a function which would set `result` to `true`. Using `result` before calling the function would yield an undefined value.

There are two solutions:

1. You can use a container (as suggested by Qnan)
2. You can use callbacks.

The second approach means: Instead of using `result` right away, you let the function behind `object.event` call some code of you as soon as `result` has some useful value:

```
object.event = function(){
    result = true;
    callback(result);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'm familiar with callbacks after using them in C#. Thanks.